# Denoise image without converting to latent space?

Tags: stable-diffusion

KSampler requires using a variational autoencoder to convert an initial image to latent space before it tries to de-noise it. And this is awesome, but if you simply encode to latent space and decode without any treatment, you get a lot of distortion on an image.

Is there a custom node for ComfyUI that uses any model to simply de-noise an image without the latent space conversion? I always thought this was the task these models were originally designed for.

Comment: To be clear: I have actual noisy images which I want to de-noise and improve quality, not to create new images.